# QtCreator 8.1 on Windows: The application was unable to start correctly 0xC0000005

Tags: qt

Just downloaded Qtcreator 8.1 from: `https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/8.0/8.0.1/`
the installation went fine but it fails at start:

[image]

I installed an older version 8.0 but it shows the same error. I am on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Qt6 does not support Windows 7 - upgrade to a more recent version or use an older QtCreator version (5.x was the last one compiled against Qt5 iirc)

Answer (score 0):

QT 6 does not support Windows7.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).